# Convert javascript array to php array in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, laravel-5

I am passing an `ajax` call to delete some user data, and this data is passed in an hidden input, I want to convert it to a PHP Array to be able to do a `foreach` loop around it. How can I achieve that?

The values it output in `Javascript`,

```
""49,51,53,54""
```

The `PHP` code,

```
public function usersDelete(){

    $data = Input::all();
    $checkedUsers = Input::get('checkedUsers'); // data is an array

    foreach ($checkedUsers as $checkedUser) {

        User::where('id', '=', $checkedUser)->first()->delete();
    }
}
```

the problem is that it loops only one the first array value in the set of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use inputs, `$checkedUsers` is a string, an you must use `explode(',', $checkedUsers)` to convert it to array. 
Before deleting verify that user has appropriate rights to delete specified users. It is very easy to modify JavaScript and request data.

Comment: laravel has a mandatory token for every request but thanks i will implement the auth part too.

Comment: Thanks @everyone for your support in this issue i really appreciate it.

Comment: CSRF toke protects from request being forged outside your website, but it is not sufficient here, neither is user auth, it will make sure that only registered users can delete _User_. Keep in mind that client can manipulate any data before submitting form. e.g. form has set of ids [1,2,3] user can manipulate that form and send [1,2,90]. Therefore requesting deletion of _User_ 90 even though it wasn't on the original set.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use

```
User::whereIn('id',$checkedUsers)->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either send the data as array from JS using `valueFromInput.split(',')` or you can convert it in php using `explode(',', $jsData);`